# Worbooks.open refresh pivottables prompt for password even after pw is given

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm working on a workbook with a pivot table.
Data source of this pt is on another workbook, protected by a pw.

Here's my code :

```
Sub refresh_tables()

Workbooks.Open "\\srvfichiers.yhk.local\Reporting\employees\salary.xlsx", Password:="0000"
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Workbooks("salary.xlsx").Close Savechanges:=False

End sub
```

I got 2 workbooks, the first one with a pivot tables where i run my script.
And a 2nd one, the data source of my pt which is protected by a password.
I try to make a vba macro who open the data source workbook with the password, refresh my pivot table then close the data source workbook.

Problem is, when i run my macro, the data source workbook is open but i still got a prompt asking me for a password.

Comment: It depends on what it is asking. In such a workbook not only the opening password may exist... Even if it may be the same (string).